# Android browser not support long press save image(base64 ),(javascript create image)

Tags: javascript, android, html, image, base64

### 1. try canvas -> base64 -> img.src -> user long press save image

demohttp://test.m.grouplus.cn/activity/share_invitation?id=cVHPwxcgftY=

my javascript code

```
html2canvas($('#share_html'), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                var newImg =document.createElement("img");
                newImg.src =  canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
                console.log(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
                var newbody = document.body.appendChild(newImg);
                $("#share_html").remove();
            }
        });
```

iOS is  successful save image ,but android save image fail of long press

Comment: Can you share a fiddle ? Do you find any error in console (`chrome://inspect`) ?

Comment: May be pictures too big, my browser response first, but then waited for about 1 minute can be saved?, there is no error message console

Answer (score 0):

,demo2->http://test.manager.grouplus.cn/canvas.html,beacause my demo1 need phone registe